# How to temporarily lock iPad/iPhone orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation

At a certain point in my application, I would like to temporarily disable the rotation feature - effectively "lock" the orientation in code, similar to what the lock toggle switch does on the iPad in hardware.

I'm currently doing:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
```

and when I'm through, I call:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]
```

While this all appears to work, the API documentation indicates there should always be a *begin* followed by an *end* - and I'm doing it essentially in reverse.  Is there a more appropriate API for handling the "lock orientation"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's as simple as not responding to the orientation changes from your controller.  You can conditionally return true or false depending on the parameters you are passed, you don't always have to return true.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (rand()%2 == 0) { // evaluate if I should allow rotate
      return YES;
    } else {
      return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This Is what I am doing now but there is a draw back:

For example If I **0.** The device and view controller are in portrait mode. **1.** rotate the device to (let's say) landscape (the view controller rotates too), **2.** lock rotation. **3.** rotate the device to portrait (the view controller does not rotate in this case, which is fine). **4.** then unlock the rotation then the  UIViewController does not updates to portrait . I have to rotate it again to get above method called :(

Comment: In that case just listen to the accelerometer gravity and adjust yourself accordingly

Comment: Just for reference, there's also a private API way of really "locking" the rotation: UIWindow's beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Don't use this, but it's good to be aware of this, as I've been hit by a bug where Apple used this and forgot setting the corresponding endDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. (see https://github.com/steipete/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIWindow.h)